# Tensorflow model with two inputs and three inputs concatenated together

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to get the model represented by the following graphic:
[image: Neural Network Diagram]

For that purpose I wrote the following code

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
volatility = tf.keras.Input(shape=(2, ), name='GeneralParameters')
otherParameters = tf.keras.Input(shape=(3, ), name='OtherParameters')

x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="relu")(volatility)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="relu")(x)
x = tf.keras.Model(inputs=volatility, outputs=x)

y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="relu")(otherParameters)
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="relu")(y)
y = tf.keras.Model(inputs=otherParameters, outputs=y)

combined = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([x.output, y.output])
z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="relu")(combined)
z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear")(z)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[x.input, y.input], outputs=z)
```

Is this the correct code for the graphic? How do I check in general case / how do I generate the graphic from the code?

Comment: You can probably use model graphs in Tensorboard. See https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/graphs

Comment: Unless you want to train the sub graphs (x and y) separately you don't need to make a model for that. Just concat the layers.

Comment: @sachinmathewjose Input1 and Input2 are closely related to each other, so are Inputs 3 thru 5. That's why I thought the sub graphs might be better

Comment: @LadislavOndris Possibly, but I am not quite sure I understand the logic of these graphs. You have to train the model and then log it and the graphs are drawn from the logs?